# How do I share my NodeJS server online

Tags: networking, ip

Hello Guys, Let us consider I have started a NodeJS sever on my computer on port **8080**, now, I gone to find my IP address from online site, suppose my IP address is 47.29.x.x, so, I was thinking is it possible to just visit **ipaddress:8080** from any where in the world ( having internet connection ),
to get the response from my NodeJS server? 
 I have tried by using Dynamic IP address its works fine, but what about the IP address I got from www.ip-address.au, I have tried by using that IP but nothing happens. 
So, what the hell IP address was that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Internet is the normal way<sup>*</sup>: Yes

However for most home users it is common to use NAT. This is an ugly workaround to delay us running out of IPv4 addresses. It seems in use for most home users. In that case you would need **port forwarding**. Port forwarding is already described in many posts here on [SU]. If you know the term it is easy to look for.

Note that NAT also applies to many mobile networks. Only there it is carrier grade NAT.

Recapping and summarising:

- For normal Internet systems: Yes
- If home user: Yes unless using NAT. (Solutions: 1) Request a few fixed IPs and use those, or use port forwarding)
- If on mobile: Probably not unless your carrier cooperates.
- Or, use direct routable IPv6. It has been around for decades and solves the problem of running out of IPv4 addresses. With plenty IPv6 addresses per person you are back on 'the normal Internet as it was designed'. In the past people (including ISPs) were slow to implement it but these days it is common.

---

<sup>*</sup>Normal is in, the way the Internet was designed and assuming you do not block access with a firewall

Comment: Hey, This ain't, what I am asking

Comment: I just wanted to know how should I access my NodeJS server running on my phone over internet using IP address ( without port forwarding )

Comment: Ask your carrier for a permanent IP routable address for your phone. They can do that. They do not do that by default since they do not have enough IPs for everyone. You will have to ask (and possibly pay) for it and they might not be interested in it at all.